# How can Statue of Liberty walk in The City That Never Sleeps?

Tags: doctor-who

In *"Angels take Manhattan"* (the last episode of *Ponds*), we learn that *Statue of Liberty* was a Weeping Angel.

A weeping angel goes to *Quantum Lock* if someone sees it. Then, how was a megastructure as large as the Statue of Liberty able to move in New York city (The city that never sleeps) especially when it wasn't moving silently (it was making noise and vibrations while walking)?

[image: Statue of Liberty as Weeping Angel]

Comment: Very stealthily, obviously...

Comment: @Richard But, it was creating Earthquakes while walking.

Comment: Stealthy earthquakes? See below. It tiptoed.

Comment: When it comes to the Angels, Moffat plays very fast-and-loose with consistency. Lonely assassins that move incredibly fast and are physiologically required to freeze when seen in one episode; groups that move slowly in the light as long as they think they're seen in another; angels that look nothing like angels in another and can apparently move while seen; the image of an angel is an angel, unless that's inconvenient (NY post cards containing Statue of Liberty causing angel epidemic, anyone? no?)...

Comment: Step One: Coat the interior with [psychomagnotheric slime](http://ghostbusters.wikia.com/wiki/Psychomagnotheric_Slime)...

Comment: @Tim Oh crap, post cards. So many problems with that episode, and I never even thought of the post cards. "The image of an angel *is* an angel...."

Comment: It's New York City!  Nobody saw Nothin'!

Comment: They played it Jackie Wilson

Comment: Allow me to blow your mind here: not everything that happens in Las Vegas actually stays in Las Vegas.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[Says Moffat](http://www.radiotimes.com/news/2013-05-02/steven-moffat-clears-up-doctor-whos-statue-of-liberty-mystery-kind-of):

> The Angels can do so many things. They can bend time, climb inside
>   your mind, hide in pictures, steal your voice, mess with your
>   perception, leak stone from your eye… New York in 1938 was a nest of
>   Angels and the people barely more than farm animals. The abattoir of
>   the lonely assassins!
>
> In those terrible days, in that conquered city, you saw and understood
>   only what the Angels allowed, so Liberty could move and hunt as it
>   wished, in the blink of an eye, unseen by the lowly creatures upon
>   which it preyed. Also, it tiptoed.

---

Adding onto this, there is at least some in-story precedence. In "The Time of Angels", when the Doctor realizes that all of the statues on Alfava Metraxis are, in fact, Weeping Angels, he suggests that he and his party may not have noticed them because the Angels could have been generating a perception filter, although he also considers that he and his party may have instead just been "thick." However, as the Weeping Angel on the video clip managed to create a deadlock seal out of nothing earlier on in that same story, it seems entirely within the realm of possibility that Weeping Angels, especially ones as well fed (and therefore more powerful, as also elaborated in "The Time of Angels" - DOCTOR: "Dinner to an Angel. The longer we leave it there, the stronger it will grow.") as the ones in Manhattan, who had a perpetually-generating food supply, could have created a high-level perception filter that would have put peoples' attention off of the Statue of Liberty. This was actually lightly alluded to in "The Angels Take Manhattan", when Grayle said, "These things are all over, but people don't seem to notice."

Comment: I am still not convinced, but yes, how can I question words of God.. Just one thing to say (stolen from the link in answer): `We all just got Moffated. Again.`

Comment: Where Moffat seems to excel is in communication "You shouldn't ask these questions-- just have fun!" However, instead of annoyingly throwing that statement around he communicates it by constructing off-the-cuff, fantastical explanations that are just as entertaining as the story that begs for these answers.  I believe Moffat both pulled that explanation from his arse AND did such a good job responding that I don't mind that it's essentially BS.

Comment: @RLH really though, that's all a story is.

Comment: I'm still having problems suspending my disbelief for this one.

Answer (score 3):

Manhattanite here. Simple enough answers to your concerns.

1. Why don't the natives notice? Because we never look at it, unless we're on the Staten Island Ferry and really bored. That late at night, most people on the ferry are inside, trying to keep awake. These days, lower Manhattan that late is a lot more deserted than you might think in a lot of areas.
2. Why don't the tourists notice? It's night, they're all in their hotel rooms.
3. What about the postcards? I'd argue that the image of an angel is an angel only when the reproduction quality is high enough. What about that film angel? It's alien video, it could be super HD, who knows? They're quantum mechanically bound. Well, when a copy of something becomes a good enough quality copy, it becomes the thing. Which we also see later with a certain Centurion.
4. Doesn't anyone feel the earthquakes? Nope. We get them on such a rare occasion that either nobody notices (seriously, you read about it in the paper the next day in surprise) or you just shrug it off as something else. There was one a year or two ago, and I thought the building I was in was falling down. Believe me, that was a far more plausible explanation than an earthquake.